# mounted directory, can't edit file

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, nfs, mount

I have mounted a folder with my other laptop and i would like to edit files created by **admin@master** which is the main server and **admin@worker** the mounted one. **/shr** is the mounted folder, both can see the same folder and same files, both can create files however when **admin@master** create a file and **admin@worker** wants to edit it says permission denied what should i do?

**admin@master
cat /etc/exports**

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#               to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#

/shr *(rw,sync)
```

**admin@master**

```
ls -l /

drwxr-xr-x   2 nobody nogroup  4096 Nov 10 20:33 shr

ls -l /shr

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:33 samplefile
```

**admin@worker**

```
ls -l /

192.168.100.21:/shr 364G  4.2G  342G   2% /shr

ls -l /shr

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:33 samplefile

sudo touch sample2

-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Nov 10 20:33 dd
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 0 Nov 10 20:43 samplefile
```

what is the problem can someone explain me why my `admin@master` creates files with root permissions and my `admin@worker` doesn't? how to solve this?

Comment: Because you're abusing the `root` account. Use normal accounts for normal work.

Comment: It doesnt let me create a file if i dont do sudo

Comment: It will if you fix the ownership and/or permissions on the containing directory.